# Why is a local variable in Java not considered "effectively final" even though nothing modifies it afterwards?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, final

In a method I have this:

```
int x = 0
if (isA()) {
    x = 1;
} else if (isB()) {
    x = 2;
}

if (x != 0) {
    doLater(() -> showErrorMessage(x)); // compile error here
}

// no more reference to 'x' here
```

I don't understand why it produces compilation error. The error says that `x` is not final or effectively-final, so it can't be accessed from the lambda body. There is no modification to `x` after the `doLater` call, so the value of `x` is actually already determined when `doLater` is called.

I am guessing that the answer to this question is because `x` is not qualified to be called an effectively-final variable. However, I want to know what the reason is.

Can't the compiler just create a temporary final variable, effectively making the code like:

```
if (x != 0) {
    final int final_x = x;
    doLater(() -> showErrorMessage(final_x));
}
```

and everything still work the same?

Comment: Why do you think that the compiler will be able to do that?

Comment: The compiler could keep track of the last place a variable is altered, except that is not what it does.

Comment: @Tunaki because it knows that x is not modified after the lambda, so it can always ensure that x is already fixed by the time it is used.

Comment: @PeterLawrey do you know any reason why the compiler does not keep track of variable modifications? Is it just a limitation of the compiler (i.e. if more effort is put into the compiler, it is possible to make the code compilable without side-effects)?

Comment: @yuku the compiler doesn't do it because the JLS doesn't expect it to.  This is a convenience compared to explicitly making the variable `final` It is possible this will work the way you suggest in future versions.

Comment: @PeterLawrey thank you. I thought this had something to do with race condition (which I can't think of how it could ever happen). So it is actually possible to enhance the JLS (if ever) so that the compiler can compile my code.

Comment: @yuku: don’t expect this to ever happen. It would be a complication of the language rules for no benefit. After all, it’s your code that is flawed, performing unnecessary assignments. It’s better, you simplify your code rather than the Language Designers complicate Java…

Comment: @yuku Groovy, for example, allows you to use variables which could be modified at any time so it is possible, but it could introduce bugs as well.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

*Effectively final* means that it could have been made `final` i.e. it never changes. It means that effectively, the variable could be a `final` one.

The problem is that it doesn't keep track of the last time you changed it, but rather, did you ever change it.  Change your `if` statement to

```
int x;
if (isA()) {
    x = 1;
} else if (isB()) {
    x = 2;
}  else {
    x = 0;
}
```

or

```
int x = isA() ? 1 : 
        isB() ? 2 : 0;
```

Comment: Probably my question is not exactly correct. What I am wondering is why the specification of an 'effectively-final' variable does not apply for my sample code? More like "why the decision of the JLS is not so?".

Comment: @yuku A final variable or field can by definition only be assigned exactly once. For a variable, that is usually in an initializer. For a field, that is usually in the constructor. The key phrase is *assigned exactly once*, which is the litmus test for final. *Effectively final* simply means that is acts final without being declared so. When you initialize to 0, *then* change to 1 or 2, it is not final in any meaning of the word.

Answer (score 3):

Your `x` variable *would have been* effectively final it it was initialized once and not changed again under any circumstances. If you had only:

```
int x = 0;
doLater(() -> showErrorMessage(x));
```

then it would have compiled.

However, adding conditions that *might* change the variable's value

```
int x = 0;
if (isA()) {
    x = 1;
} else if (isB()) {
    x = 2;
}
```

makes the variable being not effectively final and thus the compile error is risen.

---

Additionally, since this *pointer* approach you've implemented wouldn't work, you could refactor your code a bit to a simple if-else statement:

```
if (isA()) {
    doLater(() -> showErrorMessage(1));
} else if (isB()) {
    doLater(() -> showErrorMessage(2));
}
```

and completely get rid of `x`.

Answer (score 1):

Short version, a variable is *effectively final* if it is **assigned exactly once**, no matter which code path is executed.

Long version, quoting Java Language Specification [4.12.4. final Variables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.4) (emphasis mine):

> Certain variables that are not declared `final` are instead considered *effectively final*:
>
> - A local variable whose declarator **has an initializer** ([§14.4.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.4.2)) is *effectively final* if all of the following are true:
>
>   - It is not declared `final`.
>   - **It never occurs as the left hand side in an assignment expression** ([§15.26](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26)). (Note that the local variable declarator containing the initializer is *not* an assignment expression.)
>   - It never occurs as the operand of a prefix or postfix increment or decrement operator ([§15.14](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.14), [§15.15](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.15)).

Now, you can make it effectively final by removing the initializer, because it continues:

> - A local variable whose declarator **lacks an initializer** is *effectively final* if all of the following are true:
>
>   - It is not declared `final`.
>   - **Whenever it occurs as the left hand side in an assignment expression, it is definitely unassigned and not definitely assigned before the assignment**; that is, it is definitely unassigned and not definitely assigned after the right hand side of the assignment expression ([§16 (Definite Assignment)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-16.html)).
>   - It never occurs as the operand of a prefix or postfix increment or decrement operator.